# Multithreading Linux vs Windows

Tags: linux, windows, multithreading, porting

I am porting one Linux Application to Windows. I observed many changes need to be done in multithreading part.

what will be the equivalent structure for "pthread_t" (which is in Linux), in windows?

what will be the equivalent for  structure for "pthread_attr_t" (which is in Linux), in windows?

Can you please guide me some tips while porting.

Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried googling it? There's a plethora of guides around.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to `pthread_t` would be (as is so often the case) a `HANDLE` on Windows - which is what [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns.

There is no direct equivalent of `pthread_attr_t`. Instead, the attributes of a flag such as the stack size, whether the thread is initially suspended and other things are passed to `CreateThread` via arguments.

In the cases I saw so far, writing a small wrapper around pthreads so that you can have an alternative implementation for Windows was surprisingly simple. The most irritating thing for me was that on Windows, a Mutex is not the same thing as on Linux: on Windows, it's a handle which can be accessed from multiple processes. The thing which the pthread library calls mutex is called "critical section" on Windows.

That being said, if you find yourself finding more than just a few dozen lines of wrapper code you might want have a look at the c++11 [thread library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) or at the [thread support in Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread.html) to avoid reinventing the wheel (and possibly wrongly so).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your tip - "pthread is POSIX".

Mingw has pthreads,
Cygwin have pthreads and so on.

My advice is to stick with mingw and try not to do any changes.

Comment: You mean...I need not to change the code, when i run it on "Mingw" or "Cygwin" . currently am using code::Blocks IDE....

Comment: @user2645956: AFAIK, MinGW does _not_ include pthreads, but there is a pthreads implementation for Windows that works fine with MinGW (and VC++, I think) and will make your life much easier. See [this FAQ](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/pthreads_library) for details.